# How to put a lot of numbers in an array and than use them in flatlist?

Tags: react-native

I got this bunch of buttnos and i need to make a horizontal flatlist in react native and i always get some error so can someone help me how to do that? I need to put these buttons in an array so i can put tham in that flatlist i need to make but i am stuck here :D i am new to reactnative so if someone can help me thanks <3

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingTop: 5}}>
                <View style={{width: '15%', paddingRight: 5}}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={[styles.buttonText]}
                      activeOpacity = {.5}
                      onPress={ ()=>this.setState({...this.state, location: 'details'}) }>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Details</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{width: '15%', paddingRight: 5}}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={[styles.buttonText]}
                      activeOpacity = {.5}
                      onPress={ ()=>this.setState({...this.state, location: 'users'}) }>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Users</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{width: '15%', paddingRight: 5}}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={[styles.buttonText]}
                      activeOpacity = {.5}
                      onPress={ ()=>this.setState({...this.state, location: 'assets'}) }>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Assets</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{width: '15%', paddingRight: 5}}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={[styles.buttonText]}
                      activeOpacity = {.5}
                      onPress={ ()=>this.setState({...this.state, location: 'sites'}) }>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sites</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{width: '15%', paddingRight: 5}}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      style={[styles.buttonText]}
                      activeOpacity = {.5}
                      onPress={ ()=>this.setState({...this.state, location: 'cards'}) }>
                          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Cards</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't make the full array, but this should give you the idea:

```
const buttons = [{title: "Users", location: "users"},{title: "Details", location: "details"}]
```

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList 
        horizontal
        data={buttons}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.location}
        renderItem={({item}) => 
          <TouchableOpacity
           style={[styles.buttonText]}
           activeOpacity = {.5}
           onPress={ ()=>this.setState({...this.state, location: item.location}) }>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.title}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      />
    </View>
```

If you titles and locations were always just capitalized versions of each other, you could simplify the array even further.

Comment: Oh I see this was helpfull i see where u put the buttons Thank You a lot <3

Comment: Sure. If this helped you, you can use the green check mark to mark it as accepted and you can use the up arrow to mark it as a helpful answer.

Comment: I am sorry now the buttons are so close neer each other like there is no space between tham so do u know where to add some style and what style to add to make some extra space between <3

Comment: Either add to your existing `buttonText` style or use something like `style={[styles.buttonText, {marginRight: 10}]}`

Answer (score 1):

The exact code example is available directly on first load, on the [flatlist documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) page.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```

You just need to add the props `horizontal` in the Flatlist component to make it horizontal.

Comment: Wow thank you u showed me everything but i dont understand how to put those buttons in the array there. They need to have these styles and on press they need to set that state and i dont understund where u did that :D